# How can I get the Ember.Route instance for a given path

Tags: ember.js

I can get the current path using:

```
App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('currentPath')
```

But then how can I get the Route instance for that path?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var pathName = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('currentPath');
var route = App.__container__.lookup('route:' + pathName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentRouteName")
```